# How to use Hibernate when you dont know what is in database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm currently working on Database manager(simple phpmyadmin/pgAdming) - personal project.

The problem is that I would like to use hibernate, but in the past i was working with hibernate only when I had one main database, for example shopApp, so I could create models with annotations.

Does anyone has any idea how to start? Currently I'm doing this with plain JDBC, with created class like Database, Table and Column.

To be more specific.

When you are working with database for shopApp you have for example product, customer table and you know every column attributes like name, type etc. So creating class model for table is 'easy'.

But in database manager like phpmyadming or pgadming, you have access to every db and you dont know what kind of tables they are holding. So you cant create model for tables like you would do it with normal project. So my question is is there any option to use hibernate with this kind of task? And if yes, how to map database/tables to java class.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do and what you do not know how to do?

Comment: Hibernate is an obfuscation layer that takes away the control over your SQL - that contradicts the intention to write a SQL tool where the user should have complete control over the SQL that is entered.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, ah, i thought there is some way to do it